# Rename FASTA files with part of their first line

Tags: bash, fasta

I'd like to rename some genome FASTA files using some information of the first line, but I can't figure it out.

Here is an example, two files:

`GCA_000007365.1_ASM736v1_genomic.fna`:

```
>AE013218.1 Buchnera aphidicola str. Sg (Schizaphis graminum), complete genome
ATGTCAAAGTCGTATTTAAAAAATTTTGATGTTATTGTTATTGGTGGAGGGCATGCTGGCACTGAAGCTGCAGCAGCCTC
TGCAAGAGTAGGTTGTAAAACATTATTATTAACTCAAAAAATAACTGATATAGGTGTATTATCTTGCAATCCTGCTATCG
```

`GCA_000012065.2_ASM1206v2_genomic.fna`:

```
>CP000048.1 Borrelia hermsii DAH, complete genome
TACCACTACACTTATTAATAATACATACTCACGCCTGGGGGGAAAAATTCAATAATGGAAACCTTACAAATATAAAACCA
CTACAAATAGGTATTATTCAGCATAATTATATAAATTTAACTCCTTATAATCAACATTATAAATATTACGCTTTCATTGG
```

I'd like to rename a thousand `*.fna` files with information of the first line in the  FASTA file, giving:

```
Buchnera_aphidicola_AE013218.1.fna
Borrelia_hermsii_CP000048.1.fna
```

The FASTA header remains unchanged. Just the file name.

Comment: What _exactly_ goes into the file name? The first three words in order 2, 3, 1 without the `>`, connected with underscores? Something else?

Comment: Exactly @BenjaminW. words 2, 3, 1 separated with "_" (2_3_1) without the ">" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all `.fna` files, extract the words, rearrange them with awk and put them into a `mv` command like this:

```
for fname in *.fna; do
    mv -- "$fname" \
    "$(awk 'NR==1{printf("%s_%s_%s\n",$2,$3,substr($1,2));exit}' "$fname")".fna
done
```

Adding an `echo` before the `mv` command to see its output results in

```
mv -- GCA_000007365.1_ASM736v1_genomic.fna Buchnera_aphidicola_AE013218.1.fna
mv -- GCA_000012065.2_ASM1206v2_genomic.fna Borrelia_hermsii_CP000048.1.fna
```

The `--` is to make sure that file names beginning with hyphens aren't interpreted as options to `mv`.<sup>1</sup>

Here is what the awk command in the command substitution does, more legible:

```
NR == 1 {
    printf("%s_%s_%s\n", $2, $3, substr($1, 2))
    exit
}
```

The formatting string for `printf` rearranges the first three words; `substr` remove the leading `>` from the first word. `exit` prevents from the rest of the file being processed; it wouldn't change the result, but slow things down.

---

<sup>1</sup> More portable would be `mv "./$fname" "./$( ... )"`; `--` is a GNUism, as far as I know.

Comment: So perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Hi again @BenjaminW. the problem is $2 is coming with a white space at the very begginin (trying to paste it correctly) `' Buchnera_aphidicola_AE013218.1.fna'`

Comment: @Tetraodienne Did you add the quotes properly? It could happen if you entered `" $(awk ...)".fna` instead of `"$(awk ...)".fna`, but I don't see how else. Your resulting filename starts with a blank, right?

Comment: `for fname in *.fna; do mv -- "$fname" \ "$(awk 'NR==1{printf("%s_%s_%s\n",$2,$3,substr($1,2));exit}' "$fname")".fna; done` I've just copied yours.

Comment: @Tetraodienne Ah, I see. The backslash is just there to escape the linebreak to avoid having an overly long line. The way you used it, it escaped a space before the file name. If you use the command on a single line, you have to skip the backslash.